# Event Filter is not working

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have a event listener which is not working properly and I cannot find why:

```
public void initCloseConfigurationPanelDialog(final Stage primaryStage)
    {

        final Stage dialog = new Stage();
        // If you want to freeze the background during dialog appearence set 
        dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);

        // Button "Yes"
        Button btnYes = new Button("Yes");

        btnYes.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {

                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });

        btnYes.setDefaultButton(true);

        // Button "No"
        Button btnNo = new Button("No");

        btnNo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                primaryStage.show();
                dialog.close();
            }
        });

        btnNo.setCancelButton(true);

.....................................................

        // Stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 140);
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

When I press ENTER key the `Yes`button is pressed. But when I press ESCAPE where is no change. Any idea why?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more context. What does "not working properly" mean? What do you expect the code to do if it were to work property? Why add an event filter on the yes button, rather than just using setOnAction? Why not call setDefaultButton on the yes button or setCancelButton on the cancel button instead of trying to filter enter and escape key presses?

Comment: I updated the code but again when the question dialog appears and I press ESCAPE in order to cancel and close the dialog nothing happens.

Comment: Problem is solved! Thank you for the proposals - setCancelButton and setDefaultButton.